# Unable to capture http result request headers

Tags: uipath, servicenow-rest-api

good afternoon,

I’m working on an integration of UiPath with ServiceNow and I would like to know how I can use the result of the HTTP request:

“{“result”:[{“***u_bot_ip_name***”:“teste ipname”,“***u_number***”:“RPA0001007”,“***u_bot_codigo_af_sng***”:”",“***u_bot_data_hora_sng***”:"",“***u_bot_host_name***”:“teste hostName”,“***sys_mod_count***”:“1”,“***u_bot_chassi***”:"",“sys_updated_on”:“2021-05-21 19:38:53”,“***u_bot_state_sng***”:"",“***sys_tags***”:"",“***u_bot_created_on_ref***”:"",“***u_bot_number_ref***”:"",“***u_bot_razao_social***”:"",“***u_bot_solicitacao***”:"",“***sys_id***”:“6b8d01451b987c5058df76295b4bcbba”,“***u_bot_codigo_af***”:"",“***sys_updated_by***”:“11548.111.0001RAFS”,“***sys_created_on***”:“2021-05-21 18:00:23”,“***u_bot_state***”:"",“***u_bot_updated_on_ref***”:"",“***u_bot_environment_name***”:"",“***u_bot_user_name***”:“rafael.souza1”,“***sys_created_by***”:“11548.111.0001RAFS”}]}"

To get only column headers (In Bold) in a For Each Loop

I'm storing the result of the request in an array variable `CType(out_get_JsonObj("result"), JArray)`and I can get the values ​​normally except headers:

[image: Code Example]

Can you give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the UiPath.Web.Activities package for making the HTTP request. The HttpClient activity in this package provides three outputs: response (`String`), headers (`Dictionary<String, String>`), and statusCode (`Int32`). If you need to process the response headers in a subsequent activity, you need to store it as a different variable.

Comment: Yes, I am using exactly that activity.
But when using the header output the allocated data is not what I need.
Since the result content contains the headers and values ​​I need to know how to get the Header